# How to install Linux (ElementaryOS) on a hard drive whilst preserving its files?

Tags: system-installation, elementary-os

I am currently on this screen:

[image: Linux "Install" screen]
          [<sup>(This links to the original, uncropped, version of this image.)</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfNOy.jpg)

after choosing "something else".

I have a 1 TB WD hard drive (`/dev/sdc`) onto which I want to install it. I would like to allocate 100 GB of the 1 TB to Linux.

How can I do it without erasing the files already on the hard drive? Can someone give me detailed steps? Last time I tried this, I ended up erasing my whole computer. (I am running Windows 7 64-bit.)

Comment: what partitions do you already have? What file systems are built? If this drive was previously just file storage you will need to make sure you have an empty partition to install onto.

Comment: I have only one partition, as in the picture. So, how can I create a partition? When I click the button, it prompts to erase everything.

Comment: Is /dev/sda1 a Windows installation you want to preserve?

Comment: I want to install it on sdc (the WD). So I want to preserve it's files.

Comment: Then, what prevents you from resizing the sdc1 partition?

Answer (score 4):

You should boot into Windows and resize one of the partitions.

The tool is at Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management and there under Storage -> Disk Management.

After this you can install Linux Mint into the empty space.

Comment: I have successfully installed Linux. I have also installed the boot loader onto the WD hard disk. Now, how can I boot into Linux? The hard disk is not recognized in the "temporary boot devices". I am also not able to select it from the boot order in BIOS.

Comment: This is not necessary and can cause problems if Windows decides to leave the partition with a dirty flag.

Comment: Oh ok, then how do I boot into Linux?

Comment: In some BIOSes you have another list of prioritizing the hard disks and you are only able to add one hard disk to the boot list at a time.